# Address problems with bitmap thumbnails

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, bitmap, .net

Wandering If I can get help, the combobox lists hdds, when clicked I would like the listbox to list bitmap image thumbnails from that corrosponding hdd (each selected HDD is converted to a string which I hope to use as the address to get the thumbnails, I originally had help to get this to work with just full images but because thats slow I'm experimenting with thumbnails, so far I get no errors but nothing shows in the listbox and Im sure I have binded

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Window Loaded Event
    {
        ///Load Avaliable Drives Into ComboBox
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives(); //Drive Letters, Into A String Array

        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            HDDSelectionBox.Items.Add(drive); //Adds Each Drive Letter As A Combox Box Item
        }


        string root = (HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString()); //Contains Directory Path For Images
        string[] supportedExtensions = new[] { ".bmp", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".tiff" };
        var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.*").Where(s => supportedExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower()));

        List<Photos> images = new List<Photos>();
        if (HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem != null) //If a item has been selected
        {
        foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Photos id = new Photos()
                {
                    Path = file,
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file),
                    Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
                };

                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                img.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute);
                img.EndInit();
                id.Width = img.PixelWidth;
                id.Height = img.PixelHeight;

                // I couldn't find file size in BitmapImage
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                id.Size = fi.Length;
                images.Add(id);
            }

            ImageListBox.ItemsSource = images;
        }
    }

}


public class Photos
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A name for the image, not the file name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A description for the image.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Full path such as c:\path\to\image.png
    /// </summary>
    public string Path { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The image file name such as image.png
    /// </summary>
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The file name extension: bmp, gif, jpg, png, tiff, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The image height
    /// </summary>
    public int Height { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The image width.
    /// </summary>
    public int Width { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The file size of the image.
    /// </summary>
    public long Size { get; set; }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First create a base model that you can use to do property notifications (the XAML controls need this in order to respond to changes:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected ObservableObject()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresion)
    {
        var property = (MemberExpression)propertyExpresion.Body;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(property.Member.Name);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T refValue, T newValue, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresion)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(refValue, newValue))
        {
            refValue = newValue;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyExpresion);
        }
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T refValue, T newValue, Action valueChanged)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(refValue, newValue))
        {
            refValue = newValue;
            valueChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T refValue, string propertyName, T newValue)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(refValue, newValue))
        {
            refValue = newValue;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now create a model that enumerates your hard drive and images and creates thumbnails:

```
public class ImagesModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _HardDrives;
    public ObservableCollection<string> HardDrives
    {
        get {return this._HardDrives;}
        set {this._HardDrives = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => this.HardDrives);}
    }

    private string _CurrentDrive;
    public string CurrentDrive
    {
        get {return this._CurrentDrive;}
        set {
            this._CurrentDrive = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentDrive);

            // enumerate files in this drives
            string[] supportedExtensions = new[] { ".bmp", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".tiff" };
            this.Images = new ObservableCollection<PhotoModel>(
                System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(value, "*.*")
                .Where(s => supportedExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower()))
                .Select(filename => new PhotoModel(filename)));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> _Images;
    public ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> Images
    {
        get {return this._Images;}
        set {this._Images = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Images);}
    }

    private PhotoModel _CurrentImage;
    public PhotoModel CurrentImage
    {
        get {return this._CurrentImage;}
        set {this._CurrentImage = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentImage);}
    }

    public ImagesModel()
    {
        this.HardDrives = new ObservableCollection<string>(Environment.GetLogicalDrives());
    }
}

public class PhotoModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _FileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get {return this._FileName;}
        private set { this._FileName = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => this.FileName);}
    }

    private ImageSource _Image;
    public ImageSource Image {
        get {return this._Image;}
        private set {this._Image = value;OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Image);}
    }

    public PhotoModel(string filename)
    {
        this.FileName = filename;
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Absolute);
        img.DecodePixelWidth = 64;  // or whatever
        img.EndInit();
        this.Image = img;
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to create an instance of this class and assign it to your windows's DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ImagesModel();
    }
```

Finally add your ComboBox and ListBox to the window, set up your bindings and override the ListBox item template to display the images:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding HardDrives}" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentDrive}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="212" Margin="27,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding Image}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Actually the majority of that code is related to property notification so that XAML can bind correctly to your code...strip away all that stuff and you'll see it's actually quite straightforward. In a real-world application (a database app, say) you typically set up the architecture using CastleProxy or something to create wrapper classes that generate all that code for you automatically. For basic stuff like this though it's easy enough to just do it as you need it, once you've got that ObservableObject class.

Comment: Im just new to modelling, Ive slowly grasped the idea of binding, resources and data template etc but havnt spent much time on models and notifications etc, so hopefully it isnt to difficult to get my head around the models thing

Comment: could you possibly tell me why there is photo model and images model I could guess what current hardrive is, but why that and this.hardrives? im trying to research mvvm, from various sources plus the code you gave but I find it confusing how one models name sounds similar to another, much appreciated if you could give a beginner like myself some clarity?

Comment: I wasn't specifically trying to do mvvm but I guess you could say that PhotosModel is the "model" part of mvvm and ImagesModel is the "view model". PhotoModel contains the information for a single photo. ImagesModel represents all the data and state for the page you're displaying i.e. it contains the list of photos, the list of hard drives and the currently selected hard drive and photo (the latter of which isn't actually needed for this example but you'll probably need it at some point which is why i left it in).

Comment: do you know how I may go about if something else also needs to check for current selected drive? if I had a second listbox that needed to also list something from the hdd, what I'm getting at is there any way I can get the current selected hdd again without the whole get; set; paragraph again? I know this may not make sense